# botframework V4 - Package on Nuget is older than the one on GitHub

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm exploring the Microsoft Bot Framework V4 and I'm currently checking the **CafeBot Sample** found at [BotFramework Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/blob/contosocafe-v4-dotnet/docs-samples/V4/dotnet/ContosoCafe). When moving it locally, I can't build it because it seems that the preview version of the `Bot.Builder` package on nuget is older than the one with the changes committed on GitHub.

One particular line of code that is failing is the `OnTurnError` option in the `BotFrameworkOptions` which does not exist in the current nuget package but can be found in the source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/master/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/BotAdapter.cs#L44).

In addition, the version used within the sample is a stable 4.0 one, which cannot be found If I create a new project from within Visual Studio following [this guide](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/05/07/build-a-microsoft-bot-framework-bot-with-the-bot-builder-sdk-v4/).

[image: Illustration of the problem]

Therefore, how can I use the newer version of `botframework` with my own project and compile it as well? Should I include a new nuget source somehow to get newer prerelease packages?

Comment: I can reproduce same issue: "Unable to find a stable package Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core with version (>= 4.0.0.37534)", you can try to [create an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/issues) to report it.

Comment: @FeiHan Thank you for that, here's the link: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/issues/41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got solved with the release of the Bot Framework V4 Stable release.

Issue on GitHub: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Samples/issues/41